# Javascript - Storing function in object - bad practice?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Is it considered bad coding-practice to store functions in an object instead of just defining them (and therefore globally)?

Consider:

1.

```
Foo = {
    bar: function() {
        alert("baz");
    }   
}
```

`Foo.bar();`

vs.

2.

```
function bar() {
    alert("baz");
}
```

`bar();`

Sure, it might be slightly less code for the second example, but when you start to get lots of functions - it will get messy.
I find it way, way, cleaner to, for example, use `Game.update()` instead of using updateGame(); or similar. When getting deeper, like `Game.notify.admin(id)` and so on, it gives you even prettier code.

**Is there any downsides by storing a function in an object?**

Comment: No. If there were, frameworks with millions of users worldwide would not do that.

Comment: No. That's standard namespacing to avoid global pollution as your question already pointed out. Why would it be bad?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The first approach is preferred. This way you are explicitly defining the scope of your functions instead of polluting the global scope. There are no downsides of using the first approach. Only upsides :-)

Conclusion: always use the first approach to define functions. The second is like javascript in the 90s, let's leave it rest in peace back in the past and use proper scoping.

Comment: There are some downsides to nesting aggressively. Putting _functions_ on objects "because it's better" for example is stupid. (putting functions in global scope is also stupid, but that's not what were dealing with, assume module scope). Also nesting objects and functions beyond 4 layers deep get's silly. ideally you want one or two layers for your object / method chain `foo.bar.baz()`

Comment: Is it really about scope? Or is it just about reducing the number of global variables to reduce the chance of duplicate variable names. Does "global pollution" have **any** other adverse side effect?

Comment: @RobG maintainability. There are plenty good reasons to attempt to reduce the number of global variables to zero.

Comment: @Raynos—yes, pointed that out in my answer, but the "polluting the global scope" mantra is greatly over used.

Comment: @RobG it's not about conflicts, it's about making sure code can't accidentally break invariants by corrupting global state. In large projects you just don't want global state rather then relying on the convention that global state is not corrupted.

Comment: How do you "corrupt global state"?

Comment: @RobG - Could be wrong, but I think his point is that it forces modularity.  Basically if everyone were in global state, it entices that hacker mentality where "oh it's easy because I can set x = 5 here and that solves my problem".  Still I see your point, as that's simply bad coding practice and not global state being inherently bad.  I'm glad you said something because I hadn't thought about it prior.

Comment: @PhilOlson—simply storing values in an object has no benefits over using variables. If modularity is desired (and modularity is a good idea), then there is the module pattern, which only exposes those properties that need to be exposed and hides the rest in a separate execution context.

Answer (score 5):

There is no magic with namespace objects, nor will you necessarily have any issues if you use lots of global variables. 
The main reason to use "namespace" objects is to reduce the potential for duplicate global variable names. A second reason is to group similar functions together for convenience, e.g:

```
// Object example (suggested best practice):
// DOM functions are under myLib.dom
myLib.dom.someDOMFunction0;
myLib.dom.someDOMFunction1;

// Utility functions are under myLib.util
myLib.util.someUtilityFunction0;
myLib.util.someUtilityFunction1;
```

Note that the above has practically the same chance of duplicates as similarly global variables:

```
// Global variable example:
myLib_dom_someDOMFunction0;
myLib_dom_someDOMFunction1;

myLib_util_someUtilityFunction0;
myLib_util_someUtilityFunction1;
```

Of course the former is generally preferred because it seen as easier to work with. I'm not advocating that you adopt the second approach (I use the first), just pointing out that while there is an issue with creating lots of global variables, so–called "global namespace pollution" is greatly overrated as a hazard.

Answer (score 4):

In this specific case go with the first one. But if you Foo object gets really complex you might want to use another approach that will give you the opportunity to use a constructor. And also the first approach sometimes is not the best when it comes to the function's scope:

```
function Foo(appName){
    this.name = appName;      
}

Foo.prototype.Bar = function(){
   alert(this.name)
}

var a = new Foo("baz");
a.Bar();
```

Comment: Anti pattern detected. Please use the prototype, thank you.

Comment: Your're right @Raynos, the problem with declaring functions inside of a function is that it will be recreated every time you initiate the class.