# How can I call a function stored in an object that is being used as an argument for another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, arguments

I'll be honest, I'm in way over my head with this one. Any help would be appreciated.

**OBJECTIVE**

I want to call a function called restart, but the function is inside an object and is being passed to a function `Class.extend`.

The code I'm working with is

```
    var Chickenz = Class.extend(
{
        init: function(value) 
        {
           //do something
        },
        // restart game
        restart: function() 
        {
            this.score.restart();  
            //etc
        }
});
```

What have I tried?

`restart();` Doesn't work. I get `TypeError: restart is not a function`  No biggy I didn't expect it to work.
Based on this question >
[Javascript - Storing function in object - bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902687/javascript-storing-function-in-object-bad-practice)
I thought I could do something like `Chickenz.restart();` but it's more complicated, because of Class.extend

I've included code for Class.extend towards the bottom of this question.

Later the restart function is called with the following code

```
/* GUI Events */
            // restart button
            addEvent($("restart"), "click", function() {
                self.restart();
                return false;
            });
```

I thought I would try `self.restart();` but that didn't work- `TypeError: self.restart is not a function.`

**So my question.**

How can I call the restart function?

**CODE for Class.extend**

```
var initializing = false;
  // The base Class implementation (does nothing)
  this.Class = function(){};
  // Create a new Class that inherits from this class
// Create a new Class that inherits from this class
  Class.extend = function(prop) {
    var _super = this.prototype,
        prototype,
        name,
        tmp,
        ret;

    // Instantiate a base class (but only create the instance,
    // don't run the init constructor)
    initializing = true;
    prototype = new this();
    initializing = false;

    // Copy the properties over onto the new prototype
    for ( name in prop ) {
      // Check if we're overwriting an existing function
      prototype[name] = typeof prop[name] == "function" &&
        typeof _super[name] == "function" ?
        (function(name, fn){
         return function() {
           tmp = this._super;
           // Add a new ._super() method that is the same method
           // but on the super-class
           this._super = _super[name];
           // The method only need to be bound temporarily, so we
           // remove it when we're done executing
           ret = fn.apply(this, arguments);
           this._super = tmp;
           return ret;
         };
        })(name, prop[name]) :
        prop[name];
    }
    // The dummy class constructor
    //Changed according to http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/    
    //Use the new operator to instantiation                                     
        function Class(args){
                if ( this instanceof arguments.callee ) {
                    if ( !initializing && this.init )
                        this.init.apply( this, args.callee ? args : arguments );
                } else
                    return new arguments.callee( arguments );
            };

    // Populate our constructed prototype object
    Class.prototype = prototype;
    // Enforce the constructor to be what we expect
    Class.constructor = Class;
    // And make this class extendable
    Class.extend = arguments.callee;
    return Class;
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be basing this on John Resig's example [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) You should look at how he does it :)

Class.extend returns a constructor for a class.  You can just create an instance of the class and then call it.

You need something like:

```
var chicken = new Chickenz();

chicken.restart();
```

Note that this will immediately throw an error right now though, because `this` will then be bound to the new chicken object, and the chicken doesn't have a `score.restart` function unless you have other code you aren't showing us.  I have no idea what you want that line to do, but you'll need to add a score property with a restart method to the chicken object or have the `restart` method reference something else.

Comment: Thanks for that! I haven't got it working yet, but this is definitely the right track.