# Javascript — objects containing functions with parameters

Tags: javascript, object

This is a fairly simple question, but I can't seem to find an example online. I've read up on objects and functions (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902687/javascript-storing-function-in-object-bad-practice)), but can't seem to find an example of a function within an object that accepts parameters.

In JavaScript, we can create an object, a nested object, and a method defined by a function:

```
var testObject = {
   nestedObject : {
      isNumber : function(number) { return !isNaN(number) };
   }
}
```

How can I call my function with a specific parameter? Is the following correct?

```
testObject["nestedObject"].isNumber(number)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `testObject.nestedObject.isNumber(number)` or `testObject["nestedObject"].isNumber(number)`

Comment: I think the semicolon on the third line (after return !isNaN(number) }; ) will break your code.  You can put a semicolon before that }, though.  Other than that, yes that code is correct now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You kind of have the right idea but you need to refactor your object. This is how it would be written and called.

```
var testObject =  {
   nestedObject: {
      isNumber :function(number) { return isNaN(number) }
   }
}
```

then

```
testObject.nestedObject.isNumber(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there were just a few syntax errors in your code.  Functions defined within an object behave the same way as regular functions defined outside of an object.  The only difference is that you will have to use dot notation to access the functions on objects.  So, try this code out:

```
testObject = {
    nestedObject: {
        isNumber: function(number) { return !isNaN(number) }
    }
}
```

Now, you can call isNumber like this:

```
testObject.nestedObject.isNumber(4)  // returns true
```

Note: Assuming you want your function isNumber to return true if the input is a number, we have to negate ( using ! ) the result of isNaN, as it returns true for values that are NaN.

Edit:  When accessing properties (functions or otherwise) of an object, you can use dot notation as above, or you could use bracket notation, or some combination of the two.  Here are a few examples:

```
testObject.nestedObject.isNumber(4)         // dot notation
testObject['nestedObject']['isNumber'](4)   // bracket notation
testObject['nestedObject'].isNumber(4)      // combination of both
testObject.nestedObject['isNumber'](4)      // alternative combination of both
```

There is not necessarily a right way to use bracket vs dot notation, but I think dot notation looks a little cleaner.  I guess the only advice is to try to be consistent in however you decide to write it.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
testObject[nestedObject].isNumber(number)
```

`nestedObject` will be evaluated and its value will be passed as key of the property of `testObject`. What you need is to make it literal, to tell JavaScript that that is the property key.

Just to expand the information given by Tyler, these two are equivalents:

```
testObject["nestedObject"].isNumber(number)
```

And:

```
testObject.nestedObject.isNumber(number)
```