# Is DOM based routing for JS any faster, or does it just benefit organization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

EDIT: i was talking about https://www.paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/

Sorry for lack of details.
DOM based JS has been popular for a long time - my question is, is it any faster or does it have any performance beneifts? or is it simply just a better way to organize JS?

Example:

```
FOO = {
  common : {
    init     : function(){ ... },
    finalize : function(){ ... }
  },
  shopping : {
    init     : function(){ ... },
    cart     : function(){ ... },
    category : function(){ ... }
  }
}

FOO.common.init();
FOO.shopping.init();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - Storing function in object - bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902687/javascript-storing-function-in-object-bad-practice)

Comment: There's no DOM there

Comment: FWIW this practice is called namespacing and was considered best practice before the advent of modules

Comment: @slebetman makes perfect sense, thank you! my real question was if its faster to load JS based on the body class (link provided in edit) sorry for bad question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just a better way to organize JS. It keeps your variables and functions out of the global namespace and makes them private. So in this way, your variable and function names don't get collided with other js modules/files that may have the same variable names.